# Grails Domain Object Naming Conventions breaking GORM Mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm, naming-conventions, grails-domain-class

I have an object `Job` that is subclassed into many jobTypes. The `Job` class carries a reference to many other jobs:

```
class Job {
    static hasMany = [related: Job, ...]
    static mappedBy = [related:'related']

    ...
}
```

This generates a look-up table `JOB_RELATED` that holds references between jobs.

The problem arises when I create a seperate (not extending `Job`) Domain Object named (for example) `Subcontractor`. By chance, I also have a jobType named `SubcontractorSomething`:

```
class Subcontractor {
    ...
}

class SubcontractorSomething extends Job {
    ...
}
```

Now, when I call my method to add the related jobs, everything works (In the debugger, the object is updated with the related job) and there is no error thrown, but the `JOB_RELATED` table is not updated!

```
def updateRelated = {

    jobInstance.properties = params//this adds the job to related as expected

    if (!jobInstance.hasErrors() && jobInstance.save(flush: true, validate:false)) {
        flash.message = "Yea! It Worked"//object is good and debugger shows the relation
        redirect(action: "show", id: jobInstance.id)
    }
    else {
        render(view: "addRelated", model: [jobInstance: jobInstance])
    }
}
```

When the redirected page is rendered, the new related job is not shown. Also, the table in the database is not updated.

I have experimented by removing the `SubcontractorSomething` class. When it is removed, everything works as expected. I have also added the class back, but with a different name. In this case, everything works as expected. However, anytime I add a class with the name `Subcontractor + anything`, the mapping is broken somehow and the table will not update. So, my question is:

- **Is there some naming convention in grails that is causing my database
  mapping to be broken?**

I have not been able to find ay mention of such a feature, but I know that Grails does stuff like this (ie XYZController)

Comment: You could always turn on SQL logging to see what is being performed.

Comment: I seriously doubt `Subcontractor` is a reserved word.  I would look into SQL logging as mentioned and/or providing the table explicitly within the `static mapping` closure.

Comment: Have you tried allowing validation while saving? BTW, if I'm not mistaking, `hasErrors()` is only effective *after* calling `validate()` or `save()`.

Comment: @tylerwal to clarify: my point is not that the word is reserved, but that providing a domain object that extends that word is causing the mapping to become invalid in some way. I know Grails has the convention in some cases (ie XYZController), but haven't been able to find a relationship like this between Domain objects. If there was, that might offer some insight into why this behaviour is occurring. Ya know, for Science.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, you are correct.  `validate()` needs to take place before `hasErrors()` (`save` calls `validate` internally).

Comment: Right now there isn't enough info to answer the question. A good place to start is by showing the complete code for the domain classes.